# After restart of host for single node SQL-BDC cluster endpoints are unavailable

Tags: sql-server, sql-bdc

I've had a few power outages in the recent days and my server had to restart.  The BDC cluster did not come back online.

What is the command to manually start my single node BDC cluster?

SQL-BDC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, when you restart your node, the BDC should come up.
When you boot up your single node BDC, run a `kubectl get pods -n [bdc namespace]` and see what state the pods are in. That'll help point you in the right direction.

Make sure you're running the [latest version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/big-data-cluster/release-notes-big-data-cluster?view=sql-server-ver15#release-history) of BDC (CU4) and that your IP is static.